# The complement of coNP with oracle

Tags: complexity-theory

I was assuming the following equivalence in one proof:

$L \in NP^B \iff \overline{L} \in coNP^B$

here $NP^B$ is the class $NP$ with oracle acess to oracle $B$ and similarly $coNP^B$.

Is this correct? Does it matter if I give oracle acess to $B$ or to $B^c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a definition of $\mathrm{NP}^B$. A language $L$ belongs to this class if there exists a polynomial $p$ and a polytime oracle function $f$ (that is, a polytime function which has access to an oracle) such that
$$
x \in L \iff \text{there exists $y$ of size at most $p(|x|)$ such that } f^B(x,y),
$$
where the notation $f^B(x,y)$ means that we run $f$ with $B$ as the oracle.

Similarly, a language $L$ belongs to $\mathrm{coNP}^B$ if there exist $p,f$ as before such that
$$
x \in L \iff \text{for all $y$ of size at most $p(|x|)$ it holds that } f^B(x,y).
$$

Using this, it should be easy to show that $L \in \mathrm{NP}^B$ iff $\overline L \in \mathrm{coNP}^B$: given $(p,f)$ witnessing membership of $L$ in $\mathrm{NP}^B$, the pair $(p,1-f)$ witnesses the membership of $\overline L$ in $\mathrm{coNP}^B$, and vice versa.

---

Given oracle access to $B$, we can simulate oracle access to $\overline{B}$ as follows: whenever the oracle function queries $\overline{B}$, we query $B$, and reverse the answer. This increases the running time by at most a constant factor, and so a polytime oracle function with access to $\overline{B}$ can be simulated by a polytime oracle function with access to $B$. Therefore $\mathsf{NP}^B = \mathsf{NP}^{\overline{B}}$.